# Center more than one label vertically and horizontally in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm new programming IOS and I want to create a interface like this:

[image]

but I'm not being able to center vertically and horizontally those five labels marked with a red square because they stack over each other.

So, my question is how can I center vertically and horizontally a group of labels in order to get a a interface like the previous image.

At this moment my interface is like this:

[image]

Comment: This is very easy...just do center alignment for both text and the label itself...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make use of stack view Follow following steps

**1)** add 5 labels as you require with constraints as you want

[image]

**2)** now select all the labels you created with constraints and all of them in a stack View by pressing stack option in storyboard at bottom right second option

[image]

**3)** now you will notice all the constraints provided to labels are nil and embedded in stackView now need to provide constraint to stackView. opt for horizontally and vertically in container

[image]

**4)** here is the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the labels in the stack,

Select the stack and change its alignment property from Leading to center.

If you want the stack of labels to be at the center of the screen,
Set the alignment in autolayout to horizontally in container
And vertically in container.

Answer (score 0):

A stack is probably the best choice for this.

[image: Add some labels]
[image: Select the labels]
[image: Click the "Stack" button]
[image: Labels are now in a stack]
[image: Center the stack horizontally and vertically]